# According to Biblical Unitarianism does belief in the Trinity disqualify one from salvation?

Tags: soteriology, trinity, unitarianism

According to Biblical Unitarianism does belief in the Trinity disqualify one from salvation?

*Note:  this is not asking whether non-trinitarianism is true or whether a trinitarian baptism is valid but whether a trinitarian is saved according to Biblical Unitarian doctrine.

Comment: Are you asking about a specific unitarian church? Unitarianism involves all sorts of strands.

Comment: You may or may not be aware, but there are two major groups of Unitarians: [Biblical Unitarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_unitarianism) (this is the official term, not an endorsement of their beliefs) and [Unitarian Universalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarian_Universalism). These two groups naturally would have different answers to this question. Are you thinking only of the first?

Answer (score 1):

No, but here's why.

Biblical Unitarianism is Christian - they believe in a God, creator of all things, His son Jesus and the holy spirit.

They believe in the salvation plan the bible outlines and that it is only possible in and through the name of Jesus and trusting in his sacrifice for all sin.

This arrangement is offered by God through His grace. There is no salvation that men can earn or expect to receive by any 'good works' or law keeping.

**God knows the broken and corrupted nature of all men. He knows the cause of it (the devil) and has provided the remedy for it in Jesus.**

When we die in this life, we will all die with many wrong understandings and false beliefs - we can never be 100% correct. The deception that has been foisted onto the world includes religious confusion resulting in myriad religions and Christian denominations.

God is well aware of all this and it is entirely covered by the bold paragraph.

If a believer (in God) dies believing a 3in1 God, they have two possible futures.

1. God has deemed them a 'saint' and will be raised to meet Christ at his return. This is regardless of their 3in1 understanding/belief, but of their faithful living according to the calling God has placed on their life.
2. They will be raised in the second resurrection with all others to finally know the true God and the salvation offering in Christ.

The very concept of whether a man's teaching/biblical interpretation has any bearing on the salvation God offers through grace via His son is abhorrent. Man has nothing to do with this *core process* by which God desires for 'all men to be saved'.

For a general overview of salvation as outlined above: [Becoming a Christian: Why? What? How? (Biblical Unitarian)](https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/articles/becoming-a-christian-why-what-how)

Comment: "The very concept of whether a man's teaching/biblical interpretation has any bearing on the salvation God offers through grace via His son is abhorrent."  What then is the purpose of teaching and protecting sound doctrine (2 Tim 4:3)?

Comment: The involvement of men is going to be faulty - there are many versions of this 'truth' so some are incorrect - this does not change what God has provided. Whether there is a hell or eternal punishment is irrelevant to the fact that Christ is our sacrifice and all are included. If one teaches a 3in1 God, this changes nothing of the true gospel message and purpose.

Comment: The *purpose* to perhaps answer your query more succinctly, is to share the gospel message by words and lives - mostly I say by lives lived in accord with the two commands. God can work through faulty gospel messages as well as correct - but He would judge (not condemn) accordingly those who propagate the more faulty/unbiblical messages.